# screen turns blank after pluging HDMI cable

Tags: 12.04, updates, hdmi

am having a problem with ubuntu 12.04LTS .it seems like there is a serious bug in ubuntu because after pluging my HDMI cable my laptop screen turns completely blank even the tv gives " no signal" message but ubuntu is still working because i can hear sounds when trying to adjust the volume from keyboard

**HARDWARE DETAILS**
LENOVO Z50-70
Intel I5 4210u
A disabled nvidia GT840 card (from BIOS)

Note: this is a new problem ,everything was fine but it seems to be an update bug because i remember that i have installed some security's updates recently